# Chaining operators to identify value where record is closest to a number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` `df`:

```
id  Volume  time_norm   time_norm_ratio speed   BPR_free_speed  free_flow_speed capacity_speed  dev_free_flow
9SOUTHBOUND 1474    85  1.794392523 8.947916667 17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 0.919879283
9SOUTHBOUND 1375    17  1.158878505 13.85483871 17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 5.826801327
9SOUTHBOUND 1052    22  1.205607477 13.31782946 17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 5.289792074
9SOUTHBOUND 986 21  1.196261682 13.421875   17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 5.393837617
9SOUTHBOUND 1071    15  1.140186916 14.08196721 17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 6.05392983
9SOUTHBOUND 1206    34  1.317757009 12.18439716 17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 4.15635978
9SOUTHBOUND 1222    34  1.317757009 12.18439716 17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 4.15635978
9SOUTHBOUND 1408    33  1.308411215 12.27142857 17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 4.243391188
9SOUTHBOUND 1604    69  1.644859813 9.761363636 17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 1.733326253
9SOUTHBOUND 1731    124 2.158878505 7.437229437 17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 -0.590807946
9SOUTHBOUND 1596    640 6.981308411 2.299866131 17.88   16.05607477 8.028037383 -5.728171252
9NORTHBOUND 449 17  1.17    14.66666667 17.88   17.16   8.58    6.086666667
9NORTHBOUND 299 17  1.17    14.66666667 17.88   17.16   8.58    6.086666667
9NORTHBOUND 241 18  1.18    14.54237288 17.88   17.16   8.58    5.962372881
9NORTHBOUND 164 13  1.13    15.18584071 17.88   17.16   8.58    6.605840708
9NORTHBOUND 142 16  1.16    14.79310345 17.88   17.16   8.58    6.213103448
9NORTHBOUND 137 15  1.15    14.92173913 17.88   17.16   8.58    6.34173913
9NORTHBOUND 196 13  1.13    15.18584071 17.88   17.16   8.58    6.605840708
```

I wish to find the `volume` when the speed is 50% of the maximum speed for each `id`. In order to do this, I found the maximum speed (`free_flow_speed`) per id, calculated 50% of this and set it to `free_flow_speed`. In order to identify which record is closest to the 50% `free_flow_speed`, I created a `dev_free_flow` column which is the difference between the given `speed` and the `free_flow_speed`. Find the record closest to zero, for each `id`, should identify the record for which to attribute the `cap_design` value.

Therefore I want to create a new column `cap_design` which is the `volume` when `diff` is closest to zero, for each `id`.

From my last SO question (I'm not having a good day here) I have created:

```
df['cap_design'] = df['Volume'].where(df.groupby('id')['diff'].transform('min'))
```

However, this returns a `cap_design` value of the `Volume` per that row, rather than the volume of the closest to zero value for `dev_free_flow`, per `id`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.Series.searchsorted()`, you can obtain the index where you should insert a given value in a sorted `Series` to maintain order (50% of `Series.max()`, in your case), which you can then use to select the matching value in another Series (`Volume`). So, using what seems to be the relevant subset of your data:

```
             id  Volume      speed
13  9NORTHBOUND     241  14.542373
11  9NORTHBOUND     449  14.666667
12  9NORTHBOUND     299  14.666667
15  9NORTHBOUND     142  14.793103
16  9NORTHBOUND     137  14.921739
14  9NORTHBOUND     164  15.185841
17  9NORTHBOUND     196  15.185841
10  9SOUTHBOUND    1596   2.299866
9   9SOUTHBOUND    1731   7.437229
0   9SOUTHBOUND    1474   8.947917
8   9SOUTHBOUND    1604   9.761364
5   9SOUTHBOUND    1206  12.184397
6   9SOUTHBOUND    1222  12.184397
7   9SOUTHBOUND    1408  12.271429
2   9SOUTHBOUND    1052  13.317829
3   9SOUTHBOUND     986  13.421875
1   9SOUTHBOUND    1375  13.854839
4   9SOUTHBOUND    1071  14.081967
```

Use:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'speed'])
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.Volume.iloc[x.speed.searchsorted(x.speed.max()*.5)])
```

to get:

```
9NORTHBOUND  13     241
9SOUTHBOUND  9     1731
Name: Volume, dtype: int64
```

If you want the result as a new column, you could do:

```
df['result'] = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.Volume.iloc[x.speed.searchsorted(x.speed.max()/2)].tolist() * len(x),index=x.index)).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

df.loc[:, ['id', 'Volume', 'speed', 'result']]

             id  Volume      speed  result
0   9NORTHBOUND     241  14.542373     241
1   9NORTHBOUND     449  14.666667     241
2   9NORTHBOUND     299  14.666667     241
3   9NORTHBOUND     142  14.793103     241
4   9NORTHBOUND     137  14.921739     241
5   9NORTHBOUND     164  15.185841     241
6   9NORTHBOUND     196  15.185841     241
7   9SOUTHBOUND    1596   2.299866    1731
8   9SOUTHBOUND    1731   7.437229    1731
9   9SOUTHBOUND    1474   8.947917    1731
10  9SOUTHBOUND    1604   9.761364    1731
11  9SOUTHBOUND    1206  12.184397    1731
12  9SOUTHBOUND    1222  12.184397    1731
13  9SOUTHBOUND    1408  12.271429    1731
14  9SOUTHBOUND    1052  13.317829    1731
15  9SOUTHBOUND     986  13.421875    1731
16  9SOUTHBOUND    1375  13.854839    1731
17  9SOUTHBOUND    1071  14.081967    1731
```